# syntax error on strings when comparing data

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

```
countries_data.head()
df["Net Migration" (per area)] = df["Net Migration (per area)"].str.replace(',', ".")
df["pop.density (per sq. mi.)"] = df["pop.density (per sq.mi )"]. str.replace(',', ".")
```

here is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-df095d585543>", line 6
    df["Net Migration" (per area)] = df["Net Migration (per area)"].str.replace(',', ".")
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df["Net Migration" (per area)]` is not a valid key to access

You are missing **""**

Change it to `df["Net Migration (per area)"]`